# Xcode and C++: Necessary to create a new project each time to run code?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am just wanting to know if there is a quick way to run a piece of C++ code in Xcode rather than having to create a new project each time?

I understand I can comment out/run different things in the same file but if working on various different items and ideas, that gets messy. Sometimes I want to be able to just quickly code and run something without going through the whole process of creating/saving a project. Sort of like a "playground" thing for C++ I guess is what I'm asking.

I am new to C++ and Xcode so thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Frankly, no, there isn't. That's why I simply have a project, Scratch, that is a simple single-file main.cpp that I hack up at my leisure. If/when I ever want to retain the code I copy the main.cpp to it's own xcode project. Fwiw, most IDEs have the same limitation in one form or another.

Comment: Ok yeah I kind of figured. That’s a good idea to have a Scratch project and work from there, will try that also. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @princeofdhump Another alternative is to use a text editor like TextMate or Visual Studio Code for small programs. TextMate has a C bundle that lets you run small C/C++ projects by pressing Cmd-R. Visual Studio Code has extensions that let you debug C++ programs and run single file C++ programs.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk thank you! I was actually doing at that one point, will try going back to it.